# does the android People app use fragments for each view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a similar technical problem I am trying to solve where I am using android's FragmentPagerAdapter to handle swipe gestures.

This is in regards to ICS...
My question is do you know or think that the android devs used fragments for switching between the groups, people, and favorites screens?

It seems like they are using listfragment

I am curious since I am considering making my fragments very content heavy and worry about performance and such.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from using heavyweight fragments with the viewpager I feel comfortable with assuming that my original question is true. Either way fragments can be used effectively with tons of operations and they seem to work great.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are relatively light weight components which can be replaced with other fragments on the fly. Even though there is no fixed guideline on how the app UI should be broken down into fragments i would suggest using a new fragment for every use case

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking for. I probably could reword my question. I simply would like to know if for example using multiple ListFragments with high-res images as tabs is bad.